# lightning checkboxgroup get last value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, checkbox, salesfoce

I want get last value in checkboxgroup. I try using `cmp.find("mygroup").get("v.value")` but it get all value.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to get last selected value of array of all selected checkboxes

```
var selectedValues = cmp.find("mygroup").get("v.value");
if(selectedValues.length != 0){
    var lastSelectedValue = selectedValues[selectedValues.length - 1]; //  desired result
}
```